# Get the parametric equation of a line

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

How I can get the parametric equation of this line?
$$r\equiv\begin{cases} x-y=2 \\2x-z+1=0\end{cases}$$
Thanks.

Comment: Let $x=t$ so express $y$ and $z$ with $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=t$. Then $y=t-2$ and $z=2t+1$.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have chosen the **X**? And if I have: **r:**   **x+y+z=1** and **2x+y=3** ?

Comment: Sorry, I add this after you answered me: And if I have: r: x+y+z=1 and 2x+y=3?

Comment: I don't know how, I got stucked in all my attemps.

Comment: Ok finally done.

Answer (score 0):

HINT : Set $x=t$, then represent each of $y,z$ by $t$.